# Is my conversion of this statement into formal language and its negation correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Every natural number is a product of two natural numbers.

$N(x)$ for $x$ is a natural number and  $a,b \in\mathbb{N}$

$$\forall x(N(x)\rightarrow \exists a\exists b(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$$

Negation:

$$\neg\forall x(N(x)\rightarrow \exists a\exists b(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$$

$$\Rightarrow \exists x \neg(N(x)\rightarrow \exists a\exists b(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$$

$$\Rightarrow \exists x (N(x)\wedge \neg\exists a\exists b(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$$

$$\Rightarrow \exists x (N(x)\wedge \forall a\forall b \neg(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$$

$$\Rightarrow \exists x (N(x)\wedge \forall a\forall b (N(a)\rightarrow N(b)\rightarrow (x \neq a\cdot b)))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is good except for the last step, converting  $\neg(N(a)\wedge N(b)\wedge (x=a\cdot b)))$.
Consider these equivalences:
$$
\begin{align}
\neg (p_1 \wedge p_2 \dots \wedge p_n \wedge q) &\iff \neg (p_1 \wedge p_2 \dots \wedge p_n)  \vee \neg  q \quad\text{(by De Morgan)} \\
&\iff (p_1 \wedge p_2 \dots \wedge p_n)  \implies \neg  q
\end{align}
$$
So the matrix (inner, unquantified formula) of your result should be
$$
(N(a)\wedge N(b)\implies (x\neq a\cdot b)) \text{.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except for changing it to $N(a) \implies N(b)$

Comment: Why should it remain $neg(N(a)\wedge N(b)$ ?